# Is ongoing download in browsers a child-process or a thread?

Tags: browser, process, multi-threaded

I was asked to give an example of parent-child process relationship with my knowledge of the following: The Parent process controls and limits the child process, it can end or start one, but this will not happen vice verse. Why I may, or may not think a download process in a browser as a child process. If browser is down, so the download is too. But what if it is a thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implementation specific. It's very possible that some browsers run each download in their own process. In that case, you'd have the classic example of parent-child-process-relationship. Some browsers run each tab in a child process, so that if one tab crashes, the other tabs continue running. That's also a basic example of client-child-processes.

But it's more likely that downloads are run in a thread, not in it's own process, because it would be inefficient to spawn an own process for something as simple as a HTTP download. You might as well check that behaviour for the web browsers you use by starting some downloads and looking in a process manager of your choice for any new child processes.

Comment: Why should I prefer running a tab inside a child if it could be a thread too? If the thread accidentally stopped it won't be able to "heart" the main process anyways

Comment: Thats a design decision. Of course, you could also implement each tab in it's own thread instead of each one in it's own process. Google chrome went for processes, firefox went for threads. Evaluating the pros and cons of each choice is beyond scope for this question. Ask your own if youre are interested :) However, it's probably worth reading the [Chrome introduction comic](https://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/small_04.html) for that matter.